# Suggested review count at top is incorrect

Tags: bug, review, top-bar

The suggested edits count at top is incorrect.
Multiple browser refreshes did not clear it.
Approving/Rejecting review decreases the count, but as you can see the count is incorrect.

[image: Bug]